# how to get the size of String when it's rendered as HTML?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Currently i'm developing a new Look and Feel and i had to start from scratch for many reasons , my biggest problem now is getting the width and height of the String in components that have `getText()` to determine where it should be painted , and i know how to get it for normal text but how to do it if it's rendered as html text ??.

using the `FontMetrics` really provided every thing needed for plain text but using it for html gives as if it's plain , so i'v tried `View.getGraphics()` and do the same thing on it with `FontMetrics` of the view object graphics but still the same while what i want is the Dimension of the text that is painted (the differences that matters like if it contains `<br />` the height will not be accurate ! or if the font is changed in html tags ,etc...)  .

```
    public Dimension getTextSize(JComponent c, Graphics g, String text) {
        //this works if you want to get the size as if it's plain text
        //and later in the drawing calculate the descent line distance to draw the text
        g.setFont(c.getFont());
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        Dimension plaintTextSize = new Dimension(fontMetrics.stringWidth(text),fontMetrics.getHeight());
        return plaintTextSize;
    }
```

i have tried the above with

```
View view = (View) JComponent.getClientProperty(BasicHTML.propertyKey);
```

and pass on the `view.getGraphics()` to the `getTextSize` method but still the same .I'v searched a lot about it but i couldn't found any relative results and i got nothing about what class to use and i can't use `TextLayout` since some times the `JComponent` might not be a `JTextComponent`  .
please help and thank you.

**Edit**

it seems like it's a real semi-impossible thing to do so as another solution am gonna settle with `View.getPreferredSpan(int axsis)` to get the size but some time's it's not reliable to scale the size , i mean like in component's we can predict this conflict but how to predict this in html string painted `BasicHTML` view to at least handle the size manually  .

Comment: Excuse me if I am stating the obvious, but have you looked at the JDK source code to see how they handle painting HTML text, for example class `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI`?

Comment: i did ! , have you ? they use ```public static String layoutCompoundLabel(JComponent c, FontMetrics fm, String text, Icon icon, int verticalAlignment, int horizontalAlignment, int verticalTextPosition, int horizontalTextPosition, Rectangle viewR, Rectangle iconR, Rectangle textR, int textIconGap)``` witch it uses a lot of memory  for a secondary method like the one am writing plus it uses a lot of parameters that i can't give and i went to that method implementation too and it ended in using an internal api static methods , any ways thanks for reply.

Comment: `layoutCompoundLabel(...)` works for me. *uses a lot of memory* - yes, well rendering HTML uses lots of resources. *it uses a lot of parameters* - you can assign default values. Or, what is the problem with just using a JLabel? A JLabel is used as the default renderer for complex components like JTable, where each cell is rendered individually. If you look at the code for the default renderer you will see some methods are overridden to prevent certain methods from being invoked to improve efficiency.

Comment: thanks for the reply @camickr , using a label is considered when making the label a sub component like in your example , i think that am gonna settle with ```View.getPreferredSpan(int axsis)``` but some times it do not give a reliable size can you give me hint here why it does ? to handle it manually and thx again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sadly searching the whole web with no any satisfying answer for the real question

> how to get the size of String when it's rendered as HTML?

but the other question after the edit of how to get differences between the real size and the preferred size of the view using

```
View.getPreferredSpan(int axsis);
```

that the return size will give the size of the typed content not the drawn one's
like 
if the text was

```
<html> 
  <body>
     first line<br />
     second line <hr />
     third line
  </body>
</html>
```

it will use the size of the

```
View.getPreferredSpan(int axsis);
```

to get the text size of the first ,second and third line sentences but it will use the `Rectangle` parameter to determine the end of that `<hr />` line .

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to do this for over 20 years, but since a JLabel will accept html, try creating a JLabel using your html text and then get the label's preferred size.

Comment: with all due respect this is a bad idea making the size depends on another component witch will consume a lot of resources (for a light painting method like ```ComponentUI.paint```) plus considering all the bean-properties changes that would fire events will take resources too , and my L&F is all about animation and i have to make the best management here to ensure that no glitches gonna happen in painting .